# Why will my loop only detect if one change is made, but not two at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication, for-loop

I figured out a way to prevent users from changing hidden input values, but only if they change one at a time. While inspecting the page if a hidden input is changed it checks against the default value set when the page loads and then if it has changed and alerts the user. Here's the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var passAlong = document.getElementById("passAlong");
    var passAlongOld = passAlong.value;
    var goThrough = document.getElementById("goThrough");
    var goThroughOld = goThrough.value;
    var passThru = document.getElementById("passThru");
    var passThruOld = passThru.value;
    var main = [passAlong, goThrough, passThru];
    var old = [passAlongOld, goThroughOld, passThruOld];

    setInterval(function() {
        for (var i = 0, l = main.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (main[i].value != old[i]) {
                main[i].value = old[i];
                alert("Please don't change the code, thanks! Element changed: " + main[i].id);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Again this works and should be used to prevent things from changing client-side.
But can anyone help and make it work for if two or more elements are changed at once by the client i.e. inspecting the element and editing the html of a div and changing the values for two inputs.

Comment: *"I figured out a way to prevent users from changing hidden input values"* - Why is this even a problem that needs solving? In any case, I don't understand what you mean about making it work for two or more elements, because are you not looping through and testing *all* of the elements?

Comment: It's client-side form validation. It makes it possible to just carry data from page to page via forms, and now without changing except for the visible inputs you need from the user.

Comment: Exactly why it's odd that the loop won't alert if you change two or more when inspecting the element.

Comment: But if the end user knows how to use the browser's dev tools to change hidden input values, what makes you think they don't know how to submit the entire request via the dev tools and bypass all of your validation? Are you sure you're changing two or more within the same three-second period between checks?